# remove dotted line when we click on data in lineChart of MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

When i click on the data in map then it's automatically draw a line vertically and horizontally. I have tried everything with all properties but still not able to remove that. How can i remove that line??

**please find the attached screenshot**

[image: I want to remove those linke where we have label of 42 there we have horizontal and vertical line]

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem? If so, can you please accept to mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
mChart.getData().setHighlightEnabled(false);
```

Here is the [javadoc](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.1/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/ChartData.html) for that method:

> `void setHighlightEnabled(boolean enabled)`
>
> Enables / disables highlighting values for all DataSets this data object contains.

Answer (score 0):

The vertical and horizontal lines are drawn to mark the exact point on click. MP Android chart by default has it turned on. This feature can be edited using the highlightColor function. In the code below, I set the color to transparent and hence, was able to get rid of it.

val set = LineDataSet(values, "DataSet 2")
set.highLightColor = Color.TRANSPARENT

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.